# DVD mounted but not accessible from Finder

Tags: macos, finder, optical-drive

I have burnt a set of data DVDs on my Windows PC. These read fine on the PC, but for some reason OS X misbehaves. I have Hardware Growler installed, so when I insert the disc I get a notification that the drive has been mounted (with a label I set during burning).

The problem the disc doesn't appear on my desktop along other drives and in Finder it is greyed out and not accessible.

Interestingly enough if I use ForkLift.app it reads fine - files are being opened in their respective apps without any problem. Can access it from Terminal, too.

There is an ampersand character in the disc's label - could this be a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed - it turned out the ampersand was causing the issue. The same DVD without the apostrophe in the DVD label works just fine.